# Padding changes when the browser is zoomed in or out

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-position

I have a thumbnail image and another smaller image which overlaps the thumbnail image. But the padding changes for the smaller overlapping image as I zoom in and out and the problem exist only with the CHROME browser. Its working fine with IE and firefox. I tried using percentage to set the padding values for the smaller image but the problem still exist. 
Here are the images.

[image: 0 Zoom]

[image: With Zoom]

This is the HTML

```
   <div class="car-item">
                         <div class=" car-image">
                           <img src="/~/media/images/thumb.ashx" alt="Image 1" />
                         </div>

                            <div class="car video">
                                <a href="#">VIDEO</a>
                            </div>

    <div>
```

position for car video is absolute
position for car item is  relative
and for car-image is static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have issues at times when using percentages.  This is a good example of when to use `absolute positioning`.

I have no idea what your code looks like so here is a basic example of how to accomplish what you have pictured above with absolute positioning. I used a span tag instead of an additional image tag but it should work all the same.

You might have to modify your HTML and CSS a little furthor to get it to work in your environment.

http://jsfiddle.net/6C8gT/

Here is an **updated** jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/6C8gT/1/) that uses your markup and another one with reduced markup (http://jsfiddle.net/6C8gT/2/).  You don't really need those DIVs unless you have plans for them in the future.

I just did what I have posted below but modified the CSS to match your HTML.  You'll have to check out the jsFiddles.

*HTML*

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="thumb" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
    <span>Video</span>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.container img {
    display: block;
}
.container span {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```