# why does the height increase when minimizing bootstrap card

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using bootstrap cards to display different data and I want to display less cards in a row as the screen size get smaller in width. I was able to get that behavior but when the screen gets smaller, the height of the card increases dramatically. I been at this issue for about an hour and cant seem to figure out whats the issue. As you can see the first image is the normal screen and the border size is same, but when resize happens the height of the border increases which gives white space above the image. I need help in trying to remove that white space.

[image: Normal screen image]

[image: Screen Resize to smaller width]

```
const displayProfArr = noDupArr.sort((a,b) => a.name1 > b.name1 ? 1 : -1).map((data, idx) => {
      return <div class="card" style={{width: "18rem"}}>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div className="textOnImg">
                    <Link to={{pathname: "/displayGrades", state: { linkState: data }}} key={idx}>
                      <img src={pic01} alt="pic01"/>
                      <h3 class="centered">{data.name1}</h3>
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    });
```

```
return (
   <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">
          {displayProfArr}
   </div>
)
```

```
**CSS**

.textOnImg {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.centered{
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set a specific `heigh` or `max-heigh` to your cards? At the moment you only set the `width`

Comment: Please check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974877/padding-changes-when-the-browser-is-zoomed-in-or-out

Comment: Setting the max-height only helps to control the height but the image image with name moves when screen shrinks.